# How to implement a method from a derived class that does not require cast

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's suppose I have 2 classes Vehicle and Car

```
public class Vehicle {
    public List<? extends Vehicle> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    }
}

@Override
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public List<? extends Vehicle> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Car>();
    }
}
```

If I want to get a list from a class that derives Vehicle is there a way I can use getList() without having to cast?

This doesn't work(and I understand why:

```
List<Car> list = new Car().getList();
```

And this does:

```
List<Car> list = (List<Car>)new Car().getList();
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `getList()` method in the `Car` class to return a `List<Car>` instead.

```
@Override
public List<Car> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<Car>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marv is right and you can change your assignment also as below

```
List<? extends Vehicle> list = new Car().getList();
```