# Multiple inheritance and method overriding issue in java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have asked a similar question in another post ([How to implement a method from a derived class that does not require cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462420/how-to-implement-a-method-from-a-derived-class-that-does-not-require-cast)) but this is a little more specific.
Suppose I have 3 classes: Vehicle, Car, Convertible. Car extends Vehicle, and Convertible extends Car. I want a method for each class that returns a list that does not require cast at runtime. I believe it to be impossible after some thought but I also want to hear your opinion

```
public class Vehicle {
    public List<? extends Vehicle> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public List<? extends Car> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Car>();
    }
}

public class Convertible extends Car {
    @Override
    public List<? extends Convertible> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<Convertible>();
    }
}
```

In order to not use a cast I would have to return a specific type of element in the list (`List<Convertible>`) but then if I wanted to extend the class Convertible I could not do it anymore.

Is there any way around this situation?

Comment: Couldn't you force `Vehicle` to accept a generic type argument, then use that argument for the list's type?

Comment: Do you need to cast? Can't you just use `List<? extends Convertible>` as type of the variable storing the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to write

```
List<Vehicle> list1 = new Vehicle().getList();
List<Car> list2 = new Car().getList();
List<Convertible> list3 = new Convertible().getList();
```

you are out of luck. `List<Car>` is not a subtype of `List<Vehicle>` so the return types are incompatible. You can get rid of the compiler warnings using your code by writing, for example

```
List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>(new Car().getList());
```

However, I'm not really sure why the method `getList()` needs to be inherited. If you always know the type of `Vehicle` that you are calling the method on you may as well have a separate method in each class, called `getVehicleList()`, `getCarList()` and `getConvertibleList()`, returning a `List<Vehicle>`, a `List<Car>` and a `List<Convertible>` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

You can write

```
public class Vehicle<V extends Vehicle> {
    public List<V> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<V>();
    }
}

public class Car<C extends Car> extends Vehicle<C> {
}

public class Convertible extends Car<Covertible> {
}
```